# getPointerId throws exception even though index is in range

Tags: android, multi-touch

This code

```java
android.view.MotionEvent event = ...;

for(int i = 0, n = event.getPointerCount(); i < n; i++)
{
    handleTouch(event.getPointerId(i), event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
}
```

sporadically throws an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
09-03 19:43:21.996 E/AndroidRuntime( 9484): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 732
09-03 19:43:21.996 E/AndroidRuntime( 9484): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
09-03 19:43:21.996 E/AndroidRuntime( 9484):     at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetPointerId(Native Method)
09-03 19:43:21.996 E/AndroidRuntime( 9484):     at android.view.MotionEvent.getPointerId(MotionEvent.java:1927)
```

This seems quite impossible as `getPointerId` is documented to take indices from 0 `getPointerCount()-1` (see [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId%28int%29)).

The only strange thing that I'm aware of doing is that I use `GLSurfaceView.queueEvent` to pass the `MotionEvent` to the GL surface's rendering thread for processing:

```java
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event)
{
    queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            worker.handleTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

I am getting a reference to an object that I think should be immutable, and I think I'm safely passing that to another thread for processing, where I am only doing read-only access.

I am therefore moving the code that accesses the actual MotionEvent object to the UI thread, but as the problem occurs only very infrequently, I won't know if I truly fixed the problem until the app ships.

**Question**: What is really going wrong here?

**Follow-up question**: Assuming this has to do with my use of multithreading, how *do* I safely send the MotionEvent to another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, I am now convinced that the Android framework does indeed re-use the MotionEvent object after onTouchEvent returns.

Thus, the event object must not be considered an immutable object; in particular, it should not be kept beyond the end of the event handling function, or passed on to another thread.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) that you've mentioned, you need to use an index got from findPointerIndex() in the call of getX(), getY():

```
for (int i = 0, n = event.getPointerCount(); i < n; i++)
{
    int pid = event.getPointerId(i);
    int index = event.findPointerIndex(pid);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        handleTouch(pid, event.getX(index), event.getY(index));
    }
}
```

Comment: No. findPointerIndex is just the opposite of getPointerId. Thus, event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(i)) == i.